# Access DB Registry Key Temporary Issues Occurs when Changing Data Type to Long Integer

Tags: ms-access, pyodbc

When changing a data type in my Access DB from Number to Large Number I receive the following error when trying to connect to Access DB via pyodbc.

```
conn_str = (r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
r'DBQ=\\X\XXXXXX\WWWWWWWW\EEEEEEE\DDDDDDD\CCCCCC\XXXXXXX\XXXXXXXX.accdb;')

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0x2224 Thread 0x22b4 DBC 0x12894a24
```

Does this have something to do with pyodbc or is it related to Access DB 2016?  My script works fine when I have the data types set to numbers but when I change it to Large Numbers it seems to lock it up.  When I change it back to numbers the problem persists.  I have to go back to an older version of the DB for it to work again.  I've tried the restart, copy and paste into a new location but for some reason it's locking up.

Comment: As far as I know the Access ODBC driver has not yet been updated to handle "Large Number" (BIGINT) columns. The most recent version I can find is for Access 2016 RTM (released 2017-03-15).

Comment: I just ended up changing it to a short text field.  It's not the ideal solution but it works.  The numbers are unique IDs so they are not used for calculations.  Thanks for the info @GordThompson.

Comment: @GordThompson, do you know why the driver would change based on the changing of field types?